# HTMLElement.scroll() function browser compatability

Tags: javascript, html

Where can I find browser compatability information for the `HTMLElement.scroll()` function? I've looked on caniuse.com as well as the Mozilla Developer Network, but I was unable to find any information on the scroll function.

Comment: It seems to me that the `HTMLElement.scroll()` does not exist at all

Comment: It does exist, and is specified by the CSSOM view module specification, however mention of this is very rare in other documentation

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't exist and yet it is there in Chrome, inherited from the Element class (not HTMLElement in Chrome).

I dug through all references and nobody is willing to admit to its existence except here:
https://webplatform.github.io/docs/html/attributes/scroll/

It is a throwback to IE6. Presumably still unofficially supported for backwards compatibility?

Whilst that page describes its purpose with regard to the HTML or BODY elements, I actually arrived at that page from this one which listed it as a method of HTMLElement:
https://webplatform.github.io/docs/dom/HTMLElement/

Recommendation: DO NOT USE!

Answer (score 0):

That would be because it does not exist.

You've got all sorts of other options, such as [scrollTop()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop), [scrollIntoView()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView), [scrollLeft()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollLeft) etc.... But plain old `scroll()` does not exit.

A function named `scroll()` would be ambiguous. What would it do?

Comment: why would you think it doesn't exist ?, if you check `Element.prototype`, it does exist, at least in chrome

Answer (score 0):

The `Element.scroll` is added as an extension to `Element` by the CSSOM view module specification (https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom-view/#extension-to-the-element-interface). Browsers haven't been very fast in adopting everything from the CSSOM specification, so i would be careful using it. However in my opinion it should be in same level of support as `Element. scrollIntoView` which is another extension proposed by the CSSOM specification, for which you can find support info here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView#Browser_compatibility